# Nginx redirecting configuration

Tags: nginx, redirect

My initial NGINX load balancer configuration was pretty simple:

```
upstream myapp {
    server 10.11.12.13:80; #server01
    server 10.11.12.14:80; #server02
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /myapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
```

Let's say the localhost has the IP `1.2.3.4.`

**Result:** 
The user calls *1.2.3.4/myapp* and gets redirected to one of those two servers including the requested filepath.

For example: *1.2.3.4/myapp/results* gets redirected to maybe *10.11.12.13/myapp/results*.

Now I have ONE special case to include, this is where I struggle. ALL requests should still be handled exactly the same with this one exception:

If *1.2.3.4/specialFilePath* is called I want to redirect to a totally different, static URL e.g. *externalPage.com*.

Can I add this case somehow to my Nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a second *location* block in which you defile what to do with the specialFilePath like

```
location /specialFilePath  {
    proxy_pass http://externalservice.com;
}
```

Then check the configuration with *nginx -t* or *sudo nginx -t* and reload the configuration